# Criteria Query for Date Filtering with Predicates

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to filter list of AudtiTrial (entity class) based on attributes. i'm using `Criteria Builder` for my class called Audit.java having the below attributes.

```
  @Column(name = "region")
  private String region;

  @Column(name = "module")
  private String module;

  @Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date createdDate;
```

after that using criteriaQuery for the `Root` class i.e Audit.java below is the code. in service class for filtering based on `Predicates`.

```
CriteriaQuery<AuditTrail> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(AuditTrail.class);
    Root<AuditTrail> from = criteriaQuery.from(AuditTrail.class);

    List<Predicate> predicateList = getFilterPRedicates(cb, from, auditTrial);

    Predicate[] activePredicates = predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]);
    Predicate filter = cb.and(activePredicates);

    criteriaQuery.where(filter);

    CriteriaQuery<AuditTrail> select = criteriaQuery.select(from);

    return entityManager.createQuery(select).getResultList();
```

and my helper function **getFilterPRedicates**is as follows

```
public List<Predicates> getFilterPRedicates(AuditTrial auditTrial){
    if (auditTrial.getModifiedDate() != null && !auditTrial.getModifiedDate().toString().equals("")) {
          Predicate modifieddate = cb.equal(from.<Date>get("modifiedDate"), auditTrial.getModifiedDate());
          predicateList.add(modifieddate);
        }
return predicateList;
}
```

i'm calling the service from my controller class which accepts RequestParameters as Module, Region and createdDate. which inturn call service and returns the filtered data.

```
@GetMapping("/audit/filters")
  public AuditResponseObject getAudits(
      @RequestParam(value = "modifieddate", required = false, defaultValue = "")@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date  createdDate,
      @RequestParam(value = "module", required = false, defaultValue = "") String module,
      @RequestParam(value = "region", required = false, defaultValue = "") String region)
      {
       AuditTrail auditInfo = new AuditTrail();
     if (createddate != null && !createddate.toString().equals("")) {
      auditInfo.setCreatedDate(formatter.parse(formatter.format(createddate)));
    }
    auditInfo.setModule(module);
    auditInfo.setRegion(region);
    List<AuditTrail> auditList = auditTrailService.findByFilters(auditInfo);

    }
```

the dateformatter using is

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
```

> The Data stored in Postgresql is Timestamp with timezone.
>   and it's in format of
>
> `2019-06-11 17:57:38+05:30`

Filtering is Working fine for Region and Module but it's not working for the createdDate.
when i tried to hit API with `createddate = 2019-06-11T12:27:38.000+0000`
i.e CURL is below
`localhost:8080/api/audit/filters?createddate=2019-06-11T12%3A27%3A38.000%2B0000`

log shows something like below

> binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jun 11 00:00:00 IST 2019]

but the entry for above given date is present in Database.So Filtering is not happening as expected. 
where i'm wrong please help?
So it bassically should ignore the time portion of the value passed `(T12:27:38.000+0000)` in the url and should compare only date `2019-06-11` with the data present in Database. Any Help how to achieve it?

Any suggestions and corrections are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your controller method's signature. You have `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date  createdDate`. So it bassically ignores the time portion of the value you pass (`T12:27:38.000+0000`) in the url.

You can try 'DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME' like below.

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso ="DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME") Date  createdDate
```

Comment: but i need to compare date only, discarding time which is in database. any help ?